# is there another way to move to the home screen after the splash screen passes when using an animated container in the home screen?

Tags: flutter, dart

I used an animated container in my home screen, now i am trying to create a splashcreen but i find it diffilcult to return my home screen which is made up of an animated container, it gives me an error on my app immediately my splash screen passes. is there another way to move to the home screen after the splash screen passes when using an animated container in the home screen?

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return FutureBuilder(
    // Replace the 3 second delay with your initialization code:
    future: Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3)),
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      // Show splash screen while waiting for app resources to load:
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return MaterialApp(home: Splash());
      } else {
        return AnimatedContainer(child: HomeScreen());
      }
    },
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your `MaterialApp` as parent of the `FutureBuilder`:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  // Add a material app in the top-level
  return MaterialApp(
    home: FutureBuilder(
      future: Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3)),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          // Remove this material app from here since there's
          // already one in the top of the widget tree
          return Splash();
        } else {
          return AnimatedContainer(child: HomeScreen());
        }
      },
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: ': Failed assertion: line 286 pos 15: 'duration != null': is not true.  '          I still get this error

Comment: Edit your question with the full error traceback.

Answer (score 0):

simply return your splash screen in widgets build method,

and in widgets init method use Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3)).then((){

Navigator.push   whatever you want to push

})

Comment: please can you help me with a sample code for returning a screen with a widgets build method

Comment: https://github.com/dipakp2726/taskly/blob/master/lib/splash.dart,
check out this file,